# Having multiple images "linked" together with an horizontal line in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have absolutely no idea how to formulate what I am looking for correctly to get meaningful results from a search engine. So please give me directions.

In HTML, using bootstrap 4 or pure CSS/JS, I want to put multiple clicable images on the same line a "link" them together with an horizontal line. Here is a screenshot of the desired result:

[image]

I tried to get something done with `hr` and modified css with this tag, but I can't even find a way to align the `hr` and the `img` tags.

Comment: I don't think using hr will get you there. You should try creating a div with a background color, and position the images absolutely on top of that div.

Comment: It would be easier if you linked the images and created a code-sandbox I could try to solve the issue on that.

Comment: Show us your code. Does these images can go to multiple lines?

Comment: @Parsa I do not have the images yet.

Comment: @Justinas What do you need by "go to multiple lines" ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, SO is help community

Comment: There are many ways that this could be done. Answers depend on your current markup strategy. Please post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with absolutely positioned images on a div with a background-color of gray, to achieve the desired result.

Run the snippet I have provided to see the idea of how it can be done, using CSS.

```css
img{
  height: 30px; 
  width: 30px; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 10px; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.line{
  position: relative; 
  width: 500px; 
  height: 5px; 
  border-radius: 10px; 
  background-color: gray;
}
.container{
  margin-top:50px; 
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container" style="">
      <div class="line">
       <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Infobox_info_icon.svg/480px-Infobox_info_icon.svg.png">
      </div>
    </div>
```

*Note that the image background is transparent, that's why you are seeing the line behind it.*